# Can I clear an NCache cache without confirmation?

Tags: powershell, command-line, ncache

I've got an NCache implementation (configured in replicated format across a pair of servers, if that makes any difference) and I want to script clearing the cache. I've got a powershell script that calls the NCache clearcache.exe tool (in \bin\tools) with the appropriate parameters, but the tool then prompts me for confirmation that I actually *do* want to clear a non-empty cache (why yes, I do!).

I've looked at the inline help for the command (scanty) and in the NCache documentation online (http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help/main.html) without any luck for help with additional parameters (like a `--force` option or the like).

Is there any such option that would allow me to clear the cache without having to interact with the script? Is there another path to accomplishing the same thing?

Comment: Page 35 here: http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/ncache-command-line-tools-guide.pdf   (/F = force)

Comment: Thanks, David - can you make this an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at page 35 [here](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/ncache-command-line-tools-guide.pdf) (NCache Command Line Tools guide), you'll see that you can use `/F` to force a clear cache.

Comment: I found that the "/F" was case sensitive; using lower case I received an error about the server details not being configured in the client config (although they were). Switching to upper case resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Open CMD and go to NCache installation folder then bin/tools
For me it's `C:\Program Files\NCache\bin\tools`

run `clearcache.exe /?` you'll get

> C:\Program Files\NCache\bin\tools>clearcache.exe /?
>
> ```
> Alachisoft (R) NCache Utility ClearCache. Version 4.6.0.0 
> Copyright (C) Alachisoft 2015. All rights reserved.
> ```
>
> Usage: `clearcache cache-name [option[...]].`
>
> Argument:
>
> cache-name(s)
>
> ```
> Specifies one or more name(s) of caches separated by space registered on
> the server. The cache(s) with this/these name(s) is/are started on the
> server. Note: Space-separated cache names are to be specified in case of
> multiple caches.
> ```
>
> Option:
>
> ```
> /w /webcontent (Only avaiable in Enterprise edition)
> Clear Javascript and CSS only.
> ```
>
> /F /forceclear
>
> ```
> Force the clearing of the cache. If not specified, the user is asked before
> clearing the cache.
> ```
>
> /G /nologo
>
> ```
> Suppresses display of the logo banner.
> ```
>
> /?
>
> ```
> Displays a detailed help screen
> ```

so run clearcache with the `/F` or in full form `/forceclear`option

Comment: well, in the version of ncache that we're running the /F option does not show up in the /? help, so that was of no help to us. @David Brabant's answer pointed us to the actual docs online.

Comment: That's odd. Can you open up an issue ? https://github.com/Alachisoft/NCache/issues

Comment: Of course we're on 4.4, so perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Well, it should be there nonetheless.